# How to build a combination of parallel and sequential stages in Jenkins pipeline with dynamic data

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to build a Jenkins pipeline which has a combination of parallel and sequential stages. I am able to accomplish the same with static data but failing to get it working when using dynamic data, i.e. when using a parameterized build and reading data from the build parameters.

Below snippet works fine

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Parallel Tests') {
        parallel {
            stage('Ordered Tests Set') {
                stages {
                    stage('Building seq test 1') {
                        steps {
                             echo "build seq test 1"
                            }
                    }
                    stage('Building seq test 2') {
                        steps {
                               echo "build seq test 2"
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }

            stage('Building Parallel test 1') {
                steps {
                    echo "Building Parallel test 1"
                }
            }
            stage('Building Parallel test 2') {
                steps {
                   echo "Building Parallel test 2"
                }
            }   
        }

    }
}
```

}

Gives me the following execution result
[image]

Now i want to read the values from my build parameters and just loop the stages . This is what i have tried but could not get it to work. This bit of snippet is taken from another answer i found few months back in SO but unable to trace now, else would have added the link -

```
def parallelStagesMap = params['Parallel Job Set'].split(',').collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def orderedStagesMap = params['Ordered Job Set'].split(',').collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def orderedMap (){
    def orderedStagesMapList= [:]
    orderedStagesMapList['Ordered Tests Set']= {
        stage('Ordered Tests Set') {
            stages{
                orderedStagesMap
            }        
        }
    }
    return orderedStagesMapList;
}

def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
            echo "This is ${job}."
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage ("Parallel Stage to trigger Tests"){
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel orderedMap()+parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: The sequential part does not work. I am able to still get the parallel stages to run, but the "Ordered Job Set", this part does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declarative and Scripted Pipeline syntax do not mix in Pipeline, see [Pipeline Syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/). Since you are dynamically creating a Pipeline definition based on the parameters, you should most likely go completely to Scripted Syntax, unless your use-case matches `matrix`.

Removing the Declarative syntax from your Pipeline Definition would give something like below. Note that I did not test it on the live Jenkins instance.

```
def parallelStagesMap = params['Parallel Job Set'].split(',').collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def orderedStagesMap = params['Ordered Job Set'].split(',').collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def orderedMap (){
    def orderedStagesMapList= [:]
    orderedStagesMapList['Ordered Tests Set']= {
        stage('Ordered Tests Set') {
            orderedStagesMap.each { key, value ->
                value.call()
            }
        }
    }
    return orderedStagesMapList;
}

def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
            echo "This is ${job}."
        }
    }
}

stage("Parallel Stage to trigger Tests") {
    parallel orderedMap()+parallelStagesMap
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I was under the impression that by using script tags we can still use few functionalities of scripted pipeline in declarative but i guess there will always be some limitations.

Comment: Also yes my requirement is to use matrix but wanted to get something working first and your answer perfectly answers my question. Any pointers to the right direction with my scenario will equally be helpful and will appreciate. For now i can use substring and get it working which though ugly will get me up and running again with dynamic values. Thank you, i will accept your answer.

Comment: Indeed, the `script` step is an escape hatch to use scripted syntax inside the declarative one. It works well for simpler use-cases when for example step returns some value that needs to be processed. However, when Declarative is mostly used to wrap a few `script` tags, it is a sign that the pipeline definition might be too dynamic for declarative syntax.